# Calculate age of world in Islam

Tags: creation, prophet-adam

#### I have few Question About calculating time period according to Islam

**Is there anyway to calculate how long this Universe has existed for Quran or Hadith?**

**How long did Hazrat Adam(a.s) lived?**

**For how long human has been living in this world?**

I have been confused about the calculation of time these question have been in my mind for long time now. I want to if there is a answer in Islam about this. I know will be hard to tell but is there a time explanation in Islam. I know there were no units of second and hour so how Allah calculate time?

Answer (score 1):

**To say about the age of universe in terms of the time we humans use is not mentioned anywhere in the hadith or Quran. The times mentioned there in maybe [geological time]**[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Kathir)(which sees our 4.55 billion years old sun as in its teenage) and I agree with that. because this planet has existed even before Adam (AS) came to this planet as it was pre occupied with jin race and now we humans coexist with jins. Only Allah knows what was here even before jin race

**Regarding the age of Adam (AS), they probably were less than 2000 but more than a thousand years old. (infering from Ahadith - and [ibn kathir's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Kathir) book '[The stories of prophets = Qisas Al Anbiya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qisas_Al-Anbiya)')**

**Humans have existed perhaps around 80000+ years**, as there were a lot of generations of human beings we don't even know about. because they were completely destroyed by Allah  azawajjal for the reasons Allah knows best. And the people during the initial stages of man on earth lived long lives eventually decreasing to the current average of less than hundred. To even accomodate the archaeological findings which have been carbon dated require tens of housands of years.

Answer (score 1):

The Qur'an and hadith do not specify how old the universe, humanity, or the earth is. The "Days" Mentioned in creation are ambiguous references that need not be literal days. Every hadith in authentic books that seems to suggest a timeframe, such as the hadith that there are ten generations between Adam and Noah and ten generations between Noah and Abraham, can be interpreted in other ways(that it was referring to believing generations, not all generations.) According to the early Muslim commentator Mujahid each "Day" is like a thousand years.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there anyway to calculate how long this Universe has existed from the Quran or Hadith?**

Using the central text of Islam, the Holy Quran, what you are asking is not possible.

Perhaps there are some hadiths of dubious reliability that shed a glimpse on the 'age of the world', although there are none that I am particularly familiar with.

---

I do however have some (slightly) good news!

**How long did Hazrat Adam (a.s.) live?**

It is commonly accepted amongst Muslims that Adam lived to ~1000 years of age. I must stress however that there is no concrete evidence for this in the Quran or any hadith with which I am familiar. The best I can show you is found in the Book of Genesis:

> Gen 5:5
>   And all the days that Adam lived were nine hundred and thirty years: and he died. (KJV)

---

**For how long have humans been living on this world?**
Since Adam and Eve were sent here ;)

Peace be with you, Insha'Allah.

Answer (score 0):

**With respect to the age of the world, actually how to calculate it, we can say that according to a narration from Anas ibn Malik (who narrated from the prophet (SAWW) that Prophet Muhammad said:**

> The age of the world is 7 days from the days of Akherah (afterworld).
>   Allah says: a day in front of your God is like one thousand years that
>   you count.

**According to another tradition from the Messenger of Allah (SAWW), he said that**

> the world is 7.000 years and I am at the last millennium of it …

With respect to the age of Hazrat Adam, there are several different narrations such as:

> 930, 936, 1000, 1030, 1040 years…

and regarding your last question that you inquired: For how long human has been living in this world? I reckon we can calculate it since Hazrat Adam in accordance with the tradition above.

**Sources:**

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa48482

http://www.hawzah.net/fa/book/bookview/45327/35592